# How to set a combined maximum for two price set options for an event registration (e.g. youth and adult prices)

Tags: civievent, price-sets

I have an event with multiple sessions that users can register for. Some of the sessions have different prices for youth and adults. Is there any way to do this with a price set, i.e. to have two options that have a combined maximum?

For example, if I have 100 seats in a theatre for a session and I want to sell youth tickets at $10 and adult tickets at $20, how do I make sure I don't sell more than 100 tickets in total?

There are multiple sessions at the event, so using participant count wouldn't work. CiviCRM webform is an option that we've used, but that adds a lot of overhead and additional headaches to change registrations, etc., so a CiviEvent solution would be preferred.

If this isn't possible currently, is it within reason to think about an extension that allows this? It seems that this could be done by adding a maximum to a price field when it has price options and associated logic, but it would get a little complex to deal with all possible cases.